# ActionController::MissingFile (Cannot read file <filepath> ) occurs on heroku app after few hours

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I have a rails-4 application on heroku in which I (as the manager) post some pdf files (using paperclip) and users view these pdf files. When I post a pdf, all users can view it for about a couple of hours and everything is working good. But after about one or two hours, nobody (even myself) can view the pdf file. I looked at my logs and I saw that I get the following error:

```
ActionController::MissingFile (Cannot read file <filepath> )
```

Here's the code I have in my controller:

```
def view_pdf
    @exam = Exam.find(params[:id])
    @file = File.join(Rails.root, @exam.file_url)
    send_file(@file, :filename => @exam.file_file_name, :type => "application/pdf", :disposition => 'inline', :stream => :true)
end
```

I went through many of the stackoverflow questions and searched through many blogs, but didn't find an answer to my problem. All people facing this issue have the problem from the first moment, but surprisingly, it happens for me after about a couple of hours. Could anybody help me on this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

heroku is a read-only filesystem, check this article in [heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem) site. If you need to upload files maybe you should try to storage them in the cloud, using a service like Amazon S3.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So how come the files are available for about a couple of hours (or sometimes for about a day or so)?

Comment: @Mehran the files are available while the minion is running once the minion is stopped the files are erased.